# UserData has implicitly any type in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Why i am getting error here.
I am trying to map the data i get from the json placeholder api to the svelte template.
It says userData implicitly has a type any???

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Navigation from '../../navigation/+page.svelte'
    export let products = "products"
    export let userData = null

    onMount(async ()=>{

        const result = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        userData = result.data
        console.log(userData)

    })
</script>

<Navigation />
<h1>I am {products}</h1>
{#if userData != null}
<div>
    <h3>{userData.title}</h3>
    <p>{userData.id}</p>
</div>
    
{/if}
```

Comment: This is an axios response.  What does it have to do with svelte?

Comment: That is a TypeScript error, did you or someone else set up the project to type check JS?

Comment: It is a JSDoc error. i figured out the issue. After adding a JSDoc type check the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JSDoc error.
After adding a JSDoc comment. The error is then resolved.

```
 /**
 * @type {string | any[] | null}
 */
export let userData;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSDoc error. This is a TypeScript error that can be avoided by providing the necessary type information ***using*** JSDoc.

Comment: yeah. Even if you are using JSDoc and not typescript, still svelte is typechecking the files and after adding the JSDoc comment the error goes away. For someone who is working with Svelte framework for the first time, it really confuses you when you see that error in the first glance.